# in angularjs how do i get $index for each LI within different div

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

here is my code snippet.

```
<div>nike</div>
<ul>
<li id="cat-{{$index}}">csj</li>
<li id="cat-{{$index}}">appliance</li>
</ul>
<div>hulk</div>
<ul>
<li id="cat-{{$index}}">toys</li>
<li id="cat-{{$index}}">t-shirt</li>
</ul>
```

If i have to put angular snippet it would look like

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="name in category" id="cat-{{$index}}"></li>
</ul> //output : csj, appliances
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="desc in data" id="cat-{{$index}}"></li> //output: toys, t-shirt
</ul>
```

When I am trying to access "toys" by saying cat-2. It is returning me an error. When I inspected in chrome. it is giving ids as

csj - cat-0
appliances - cat-1
toys - cat-0
t-shirt - cat-1

I want it to be in ascending order meaning toys should have id cat-2 and t-shirt should have id cat-3.

Any help would be great. Is it even possible?

Comment: Where's your loop / ng-repeat?

Comment: its in my directive. <ul ng-repeat="category in data"> <li>{{category.name}}<li></ul> The second div comes from another API and I am specifically inserting values in <li>

Answer (score 0):

`$index` is part of the ng-repeat scope. If you do a ng-repeat you could use it like this:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="myLi in myArray" id="cat-{{$index}}"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Asaf - that is exactly what I have done and it it giving correct index for those li's . Now I have 2nd Div with ng-repeat and i want index to be in ascending order.

Comment: There's no ng-repeat in your question. If your original code does have it, please edit your question for us to give you a better answer